# How can I use 'checkbox' input tag in the PHP file?

Tags: php, html, input, checkbox

```
   echo "<input type="checkbox" name="h" id="cbox3" /><label for="cbox3"><img align="middle" src="/upload/JPNP033.JPG" /> </label>";
```

I am making the PHP file to show image with 'checkbox'. I want each image with one's own 'checkbox'.

I added this echo sentence in my php file but after i added this command, my file shows nothing(it doesn't work...)

Comment: Since you are using the same operator (`"`) to open the html `type` attribute, you are effectively ending the string there. Anything after that becomes a syntax error hence your file showing nothing (fatal error).

Comment: Stop using notepad when coding, guys

Comment: `my file shows nothing` - Time to [enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) - It will make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: can you recommend the program good for PHP coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, use `'` instead of `"` quotes

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="h" id="cbox3" /><label for="cbox3"><img align="middle" src="/upload/JPNP033.JPG" /> </label>';
  ...^
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes (`'`), otherwise the double quotes (`"`) will interfer with each other, causing the data not the be output:

```
 echo '<input type="checkbox" name="h" id="cbox3" /><label for="cbox3"><img align="middle" src="/upload/JPNP033.JPG" /> </label>';
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're basically doing is ending your echo by writing `"` in your HTML. What you should do is write `\"`, this basically makes it so that it ignores the `"` as PHP.

Also, as suggested, you can change every `"` (that is HTML) to `'`.

Answer (score 0):

While writing HTML content in `echo` please remember this.
If you are using double quotes `"` as outer quotes then quotes used in HTML should be single quotes `'` and Reversal.

So change  you echo syntax according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use `'` instead of `"` quotes

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="h" id="cbox3" /><label for="cbox3"><img align="middle" src="/upload/JPNP033.JPG" /> </label>';
```

but the good practice is

```
your php code here ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="h" id="cbox3" /><label for="cbox3"><img align="middle" src="/upload/JPNP033.JPG" /> </label>";
```